# What is the different between forEach and for in loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, foreach, for-in-loop

I have a below code which used forEach and for in loop. Actually when i use forEach getting correct result and when i trying to use for in loop getting wrong result. So what is the wrong in the for in loop code.

```
var currentStateValue = { dashboard: false, brandplay: false };
```

ForEach code -

```
angular.forEach(currentStateValue, function(value, key) {
      authService.isAuthorizedRole(key).then(function(permissionView) {
        if (permissionView == true) {
          currentStateValue[key] = true;
          console.log(currentStateValue);
        }
      });
    });
```

which display correct result

```
Object { dashboard: true, brandplay: false }
```

but when i used for in loop

```
for (var key in currentStateValue){
        authService.isAuthorizedRole(key).then(function(permissionView) {
          if (permissionView == true) {
            currentStateValue[key] = true;
            console.log(currentStateValue);
          }
        });
      }
```

it shows wrong result

```
Object { dashboard: false, brandplay: true }
```

Comment: for...in loop always goes the last object and change the value

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), they illustrate the difference between the looping methods:

```
var arr = [3, 5, 7];
arr.foo = 'hello';

for (var i in arr) {
   console.log(i); // logs "0", "1", "2", "foo"
}
// Where i will log the position in the list

for (var i of arr) {
   console.log(i); // logs 3, 5, 7
}
// Where i will log the actual value of the position in the list

var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

arr.forEach((element) => {
   console.log(element); // logs 3, 5, 7
});
```

> The [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method executes a provided function once for each array
>   element.

Straight from the documentation

> The for...in statement iterates a specified variable over all the
>   enumerable properties of an object. For each distinct property,
>   JavaScript executes the specified statements.
>   [...]
>   Although it may be tempting to use this as a way to iterate over Array
>   elements, the for...in statement **will return the name of your
>   user-defined properties in addition to the numeric indexes.** (*THIS IS YOUR ISSUE*) Thus it is
>   better to use a traditional for loop with a numeric index when
>   iterating over arrays, because the for...in statement iterates over
>   user-defined properties in addition to the array elements, if you
>   modify the Array object, such as adding custom properties or methods.